# Prove that if $D$ is bounded, then $\bar{D}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D ⊂ \mathbb{R}$

Let $D_A$ be the set of all accumulation points of $D$. The set $\bar{D} := D
\cup
D_A$ is called
the closure of $D$.

Show that if $D$ is bounded, then $\bar{D}$ is bounded

---

My professor discussed with me that I could prove this by contrapositive.

Let $x$ not be in $\bar{D}$, thus $x$ is not in D.

---

I can most certainly proof that if x is not in $\bar{D}$ , then x is not in $D$, however I'm somewhat lost in how this shows that $\bar{D}$ is bounded.

Comment: Is $R = \mathbb{R}$ the set of real numbers?

Comment: yes, let me edit the question.

Comment: I have seen a slick argument somewhere on the site once: If $D $ is bounded, then $D $ is contained in some closed ball. Since  $\overline D $ is the intersection of all closed sets containing  $D $, we can conclude $\overline D $ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\overline D$ were unbounded above, there would exist a sequence of elements $x_n\subset\overline D$ with $x_n>n$. Since $D$ is bounded, there is some $M$ such that $|x|<M$ for all $x\in D$. Hence for $n>M$ we have $x_n\in \overline D$. But these $x_n$ cannot be limit points of $D$, since every element of $D$ is strictly less than $M$. Hence, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $D$ is bounded, then $D\subset[a,b]$ for some interval $[a,b]$. If $x\in\mathbb R\setminus[a,b]$, then $x\notin D$ and $x$ is not an accumulation point of $D$. Therefore, $x\notin\overline D$. This proves that $\overline D\subset[a,b]$ and that therefore $\overline D$ is bounded.

Comment: what if I let $D$ be the finite subset {1,2,3,4}. $\bar{D}$  would still be bounded as its $D_A$ is just an empty set. How would I show this ?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such. Did I answer your question or not?

Comment: Well not necessarily, as $D$ can be an open or closed interval and or a finite set. For generality I would like to prove for all three.

Comment: My answer shows that $\overline D$ is bounded in full generality. Don't you agree?